# Find the largest and smallest element in arrayList from a typed in BufferedReader

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I don't know why im not geeting the smallest number. The larget number is correct if eg.try: 129, 2, 3.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int list[] = new int[3];
    int min = list[0];
    int max = list[0];
    int input;

    for (input = 0; input < list.length; input++) {
        String s = reader.readLine();
        list[input] = Integer.parseInt(s);

        if (list[input] < min) {
            min = list[input];
        } else if (list[input] > max) {
            max = list[input];
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Smallet nummber: " + min);
    System.out.println("Biggest nummber: " + max);
}
```

Comment: @tushar_lokare The IDE that OP may or may not be using has absolutely nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just initialize your min and max like this:

```
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

Also change condition part to this:

```
if (list[input] < min) {
    min = list[input];
}
if (list[input] > max) {
    max = list[input];
}
```

When you are initializing with **list[0]**, min and max both will be initialized with 0. Now if you give input value less than 0, then only **min** value will be updated. Otherwise, min value will never be updated.

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize an array like this:

```
int[] list = new int[3];
```

all its items are `0`. 
So when you initialize min and max:

```
int min = list[0];
int max = list[0];
```

you assign to both `0`.
If you want to keep just 1 loop for getting input and getting `min` and `max` you can do this:

```
if (input == 0) {
    min = list[input];          
    max = list[input];
} else if (list[input] < min) {
    min = list[input];
} else if (list[input] > max) {
    max = list[input];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

min is 0 and always smaller than list[imput]. The case:

```
if (list[input] < min) {
```

never happens.
*Use a negativ number in your arrayList ;)*